# What are the implications of integrating the Poisson bracket?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

Reading  Ref. 1  I admit I am a little lost in some places. I was hoping that someone in this area could explain the basic premise of integrating the Lie bracket and further is it connected to nlab's Quantomorphism group? If this is so, can we 'derive' a quantum system by Lie integration of a Poisson algebra of observables?

**References:**

1. M. Crainic, R. L. Fernandes, "Integrability of Poisson Brackets", *J. Differential Geometry*, **66**, (2004), 7. ([PDF](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~rfern/Meus-papers/HTML/sympint.pdf))
2. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantomorphism+group

Comment: Just a comment to the 'close' flag, why do you think this is off topic?

Comment: Just a guess, but this seems to be a "pure mathematics" question rather than a "physics" one.

Comment: At this level of formal exactitude, I should agree with @Alex_Nelson that this is worse than pure math. In physics, of course, "as every child knows" at the practical level suited for solving concrete problems, the group generated by the PBs is just $SU(\infty)$, cf [this mini review](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf).